# Сортировка результатов запроса по заданной в массиве последовательности

Tags: php, mysql

Как можно получить вывод записей из базы данных в той последовательности в которой передано id записей (у меня записи постоянно выводятся последовательно 1 - 5).

```
$connect= mysql_connect("localhost", "testing", "testing");
$select = mysql_select_db("testing", $connect); 
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

$id = "5,2,1,4,3";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN ($id)");


while ($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))  
{
    echo "<H1>$data[0] .........";
    echo "$data[2]<br></H1>";  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться MySQL-функцией `FIELD()`, которая возвращает позицию вхождения первого аргумента в список, который задается оставшимися аргументами. В качестве первого параметра передавайте значение из поля `id`, а в качестве остальных аргументов используйте значения из списка `$id`. Результат выполнения функции передавайте ключевому слову `ORDER BY`, осуществляющему сортировку результатов выборки

```
$connect= mysql_connect("localhost", "testing", "testing");
$select = mysql_select_db("testing", $connect); 
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

$id = "5,2,1,4,3";
$result = mysql_query(
  "SELECT * 
   FROM products 
   WHERE id IN ($id)
   ORDER BY FIELD(id, $id)"
);

while ($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo "<H1>$data[0] .........";
  echo "$data[2]<br></H1>";  
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. очень помогли про `ORDER BY` я знал, а `FIELD()` никогда не использовал.